# NUnit test does not recognize a class that I created - "The type or namespace name could not be found"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit-3.0

I'm setting up basic NUnit test project to test a STACK object. I have created the `MyStack` class and a `TestClass`. The `TestClass` cannot find reference to the `MyStack` class that I created.

> The type or namespace name 'MyStack' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

I'm using NUnit & NUnit3TestAdapter. I have added the project containing `MyStack` to the References of the test project.

#### TestClass

```
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace NUnit.TDDStackTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class TestClass
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestMethod()
        {
            MyStack stack = new MyStack();
        }
    }
}
```

#### MyStack

```
namespace TDDStack
{
    class MyStack
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Made it public but I'm still getting error.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see two possible issues. The first is that the `MyStack` class is `private`. C# defaults non-nested types to `private` if there is no other modifier before the `class` keyword, and nested types to `internal`.

Try adding the `public` keyword to your `MyStack` class definition:

```
public class MyStack
```

Second, `MyStack` is in the `TDDStack` namespace, but you are trying to create an instance of it in a class in the `NUnit.TDDStackTests` namespace. To fix this, you can either add a `using` statement for the namespace in the unit test:

```cs
using NUnit.Framework;
using TDDStack; // Add this

namespace NUnit.TDDStackTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class TestClass

    // etc ...
```

Or you can just prefix every usage of `MyStack` with the namespace that contains it:

```
var stack = new TDDStack.MyStack();
```

If the classes are in separate projects, you will also need to add a reference to the project containing `MyStack` in the project where you want to use it (the unit test project).

Comment: "C# defaults classes to private if there is no other modifier before the class keyword" - only for nested types. Non-nested types are internal by default. (In general, the default access level is the most restrictive that could be explicitly specified.)

Comment: I added a using statement for the namespace in the unit test - using TDDStack;
That fixed it. MANY THANKS, LEWIS!

Comment: Thanks for the correction @JonSkeet! I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Brendan Glad I could help :)